# visualizing hierarchical data

Tags: user-interface, hierarchy

I'm looking for techniques for displaying hierarchical data.

I find my experience is, unfortunately limited to how Windows presents hierarchies:

1)  TreeView - vertical expansion (as in file explorer, and Windows 7 start menu)

[image: windows explorer]
[image: Win 7 start menu treeview hierarchy]

2)  Start menus - largely horizontal expansion (XP style)

[image: xp start menu]

I'm looking for new/fresh ways to visualize hierarchical data to the user however.  Looking for studies, can be academic, still searching.  I'm currently browsing through [Hierarchical Data Visualization In Desktop Virtual Reality](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/modjeska/Pubs/modjeska_thesis.pdf), which is quite cool, looking for more input.

Comment: You find some examples and links in the following two questions: ["What's the best way to view a deep hierarchy?"](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2317) and ["Alternatives for Tree structure"](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8071).

Comment: @Howard hey um that could be an answer

Comment: Added my comment as an answer. You can accept it if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas and examples of how to display hierarchical data are discussed in the following 
two questions:

- ["What's the best way to view a deep hierarchy?"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2317)
- ["Alternatives for Tree structure"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8071)